# html after td Rowspan, the Next column data goes to next row

Tags: php, html

Following is the code

I want out put as 
http://crysol.com/crysol_soft/Test/Screenshot_3.png

With following code I am getting output as 
http://crysol.com/crysol_soft/Test/Screenshot_4.png

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Number</th>";
echo "<th>Status</th>";
echo '<tr>';
      echo "<td rowspan='5'>Cat</td>";
      for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){

      echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
        echo " </tr>";
      }
      echo "<td rowspan='10'>Good</td>";

?>
```

What are the changes required

Comment: close your </tr> after echo "<td rowspan='10'>Good</td>";

Comment: Does not work . The number 1,2,3,4,5 comes in same row as shown below http://crysol.com/crysol_soft/Test/Screenshot_5.png

Answer (score 0):

Create Table inside td:

```
<?php 
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Number</th>";
echo "<th>Status</th></tr>";
echo "<tr><td style=''>Cat</td>";
echo "<td><table style='width:100%;'>";
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1pt solid black;'>".$i.'</td>';
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></td>";
echo "<td>Good</td></tr>";
?>
```

Comment: Rowspan 10 was by mistake. But I want the status column in the last and not in middle, Infact this is just a test program. My live project has 15 Columns after column" Name".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with your desired output

used `if` condition for print only 1 time good column and used `rowspan='5'`

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Number</th>";
echo "<th>Status</th>";
echo '<tr>';
      echo "<td rowspan='5'>Cat</td>";
      for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){

        echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
        if($i==1){
            echo "<td rowspan='5'>Good</td>";
        }

        echo " </tr>";
      }



?>
```

and also you can used this code

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
        echo '<tr>';
        if($i==1){
            echo "<td rowspan='5'>Cat</td>";
        }
        echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
        if($i==1){
            echo "<td rowspan='5'>Good</td>";
        }

        echo " </tr>";
      }
```

Comment: thanks. up-vote and accept the good answer because your question will be value-able in future for other users